# Need to Know Which Query going to Execute in code igniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I got some problem in code igniter . I just want to know which query going to execute in model. I knew about last query execution using 
$this->db->last_query();

Since, I doesn't want this there are multiple queries execution so, I am not able to identify exact query . so , i want to know which query will generate in code igniter before it could execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line in your controller:

```
$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
```

Doing this you can see all the queries executed at the bottom of your pages.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$str = $this->db->last_query();
echo $str; //// Produces: SELECT * FROM sometable....
```

**[Check Manual](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/helpers.html)**

Answer (score 0):

you can check all the queries by adding `$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);` in your controller constructor or in your model function. When you will run it will show all the queries on that page.